# Reading Binary stream with many strings - checking for end of file

Tags: c#, for-loop, binaryfiles

I need to know how to get check for `EOF` in binary file with lots of `strings`. I have this record

```
public struct hiScoreValue{
    public string playerName;
    public int encryptedScoreValue;
    public string scoreMD5Checksum;
}
```

That basically loops till the end of file, except small header for file identification purposes and storing some additional `checksums` for make cheating even harder.

So what would be my best bet for checking if file has ended? Catching `EndOfStream` exception or is there simpler way, similar to one [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader):(basically getting length of stream and adding size);

Comment: Start the file with a "meta-record" that tells the number of total records in the file?

Comment: Well, I've thought about that, but it is really last resort option. I think I've might come upon solution, but need to test it to see if it's valid.